# Uso de cookies vs session en PHP

Tags: php

Actualmente tengo una intranet coporativa trabajando con variables de sesión, y lo hace muy bien. Hoy comenzaré con un proyecto para el público en general y decidí cargar el datastore en el front-side con cookies. Nunca las he usado y estoy confundido.
Mi pregunta es: ¿puedo usar una cookie para almacenar ciertos datos de un usuario que vinieron de la base de datos?

Por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION["NOMBRE"] = 'Juan Pérez';
$_SESSION["ID"] = 12345;
```

Esto me ha ayudado mucho a crear mi intranet, pero no entiendo bien si la cookie almacene los mismos datos que necesito.

Comment: hola claro que si puedes almacenar valores traidos o almacenados en una base de datos en los cookies

Comment: Pero ¿Cómo hago eso? Me podrías dar un ejemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El concepto es almacenar datos persistentes en las cargas de página para un visitante web. Las **cookies** lo almacenan directamente en el cliente. Las **sesiones** usan una cookie como un tipo de clave para asociarse con los datos almacenados en el servidor.

Se prefiere usar *sesiones* porque los valores reales están ocultos del cliente y se controla cuando los datos caducan y se vuelven inválidos. Si todo se basaba en cookies, un usuario (o un hacker) podría manipular sus datos de cookies y luego reproducir solicitudes en su sitio.

**Nota:** No creo que haya ninguna ventaja en el uso de cookies, aparte de la simplicidad. Míralo de esta manera ... ¿El usuario tiene alguna razón para conocer su ID? Normalmente, yo diría que no, el usuario no tiene necesidad de esta información. Dar información debe ser limitado en base a la necesidad de saber. ¿Qué pasa si el usuario cambia su cookie para tener un ID diferente, ¿cómo responderá su aplicación? Es un riesgo de seguridad.

Fuente [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253633/cookie-vs-session)

**Veamos un ejemplo como si se podría crear una *cookie* con los mismos datos como una *sesión***

*Creamos una Cookie*

```
//Supongamos que...
$nombre = 'Juan Pérez';
$id = '12345';

//Creamos nuestra cookie.
setcookie("nombre",$nombre,strtotime( '+30 days' ),"/",false, false);
setcookie("id",$id,strtotime( '+30 days' ),"/",false, false);
```

Manual [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php)

*Obtener cookie*

```
//Comprobamos si esta definida nuestra cookie y no NULL.
if ( isset($_COOKIE['nombre']) && isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
    //Obtenemos datos.  
    $nombreCookie = $_COOKIE['nombre'] ?: '';
    $idCookie = $_COOKIE['id'] ?: '';
    
    echo $nombreCookie;
}
```

*Si deseas destruir una cookie*

```
//Destruir cookie.
setcookie("nombre",$nombre,1,"/",false, false);
setcookie("id",$id,1,"/",false, false);
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia de seguridad, no quería cargar tanto peso del lado del server en cuando a variables de sesión, pero tienes razón. También gracias por el ejemplo de las cookies.

Comment: De nada Alberto, suerte con tu proyecto.