# cookies vs sesiones

Tags: php, cookies, sesiones

Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un sitio web y ha llegado el momento de empezar a trabajar con cookies.

Actualmente, uso sesiones para el registro de los usuarios, pero me pregunto:

- ¿Qué diferencias hay entre sesiones y cookies?
- ¿Cuáles son sus ventajas y desventajas, se puede hacer lo mismo con las dos?
- ¿Hay diferencias en cuanto a seguridad?

Comment: Aquí te dejo un enlace, a ver si te puedes servir, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56157/uso-de-cookies-vs-session-en-php/56166#56166

Comment: Una pregunta tan abierta, me parece que solo recibirá opiniones porque no contiene un contexto específico. Si buscas ideas, opiniones o recomendaciones es mejor que uses Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aun que parezcan similares cumplen funciones diferentes y son complementarias, no debería limitarse a usar una u otra.

[SESIONES](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.session.php):

La idea de las sesiones es ofrecer persistencia a ciertos datos a lo largo de las **peticiones subsiguientes**.

Permiten almacenar información de usuarios de maneara indivudual, durante la sesión. El identificador de la sesión que indica a PHP si existe o no una sesión es enviado al navegador mediante Cookies por defecto, este identificador se utiliza tambien para poder recuperar los datos de la sesión. La información de la sesión es almacenada por defecto en un archivo en la ruta establecida en la variable de entorno [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path).

El tiempo máximo de una sesión esta determinada por la variable de entorno [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) y su valor por defecto es 1440 segundos (24min). Es decir si en ese tiempo no se a recibido ninguna petición http que contenga la cookie con el id de sesión esta será propuesta para el recolector de basura, por otro lado la sesiones pueden ser [eliminadas manualmente](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php). Tambien se podrían eliminar todas las sesiones facilmente, es decir de todos los usuarios, eliminando todos los archivos de sesion en el directorio definido por [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path).

[COOKIES](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_(inform%C3%A1tica))

La idea de las coockies es ofrecer persistencia a ciertos datos a lo largo del tiempo de **vida de la cookie**.

El funcionamiento actual de las cookies esta definido en el [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6265/?include_text=1) de 2011.

Las cookies permiten almacenar información en el navegador mediante pares de datos **nombre=valor**, estos datos son enviados al servidor en cada petición.

Las cookies son parte de las cabeceras (header) de HTTP, y estas son utilizadas para crearlas o modificarlas normalmente.

El tiempo de vida de una cookie puede ser establecido al crearla definiendo el atributo *Max-Age*, si este atributo no esta presente la duracion de la cookie sera hasta que se cierre el navegador. Por otro lado los navegadores pueden no respetar el tiempo extablecido para la cookie. No hay un limite máximo de tiempo fijado, entre comillas "*puede durar el tiempo que queramos*".

Las cookies no son recomendadas para almacenar información sensible puesto que es información enviada por el cliente (y puede ser alterada) y calquier dato externo debe ser siempre tratado con recelo.

Answer (score 6):

Principalmente, una de las mayores diferencias es que la información cuando la almacenas con una `session` se guarda en el lado del servidor y la información cuando la guardas con una `cookie` se guarda en el lado del cliente.

Además, las sesiones se destruyen cuando cierras el navegador (o cuando las destruyes manualmente) mientras que las cookies permanecen por un tiempo determinado en el navegador (que pueden ser varias semanas o incluso meses).

Por lo tanto, se puede decir que las `sesiones` son más seguras que las `cookies`.

Answer (score 3):

Diferencias entre **cookies** y **sesiones**:

**Cookies**
Se ejecutan y crean del lado del cliente y pueden vivir bastante tiempo del en el navegador del usuario por ejemplo 1 año. Lo unico malo es que pueden ser manipuladas facilmente por alguien con conocimientos de javascript, sin tu concentimiento.

**Sesiones**
Se ejecutan del lado del servidor, son mas seguros que las cookies ya que no se pueden manipular con javascript del lado del cliente, y el tiempo de vida de una sesión es hasta que el usuario cierre el explorador por ejemplo "**Chrome**", "**Explorer**".

Las 2 se usan para cosas distintas, por ejemplo si quieres que un usuario inicie sesión y aunque apague su computadora quieres que siga su sesión iniciada puedes usar `cookies`, pero si solo quieres que la sesión dure el tiempo que se encuentre dentro del sitio lo puedes hacer con `sesiones` sin problema.

Espero te sirva para tomar una decisión.