# Redireccionar a un subdominio y mantener la sesion inciada con PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera saber si es posible mantener la sesión con la que se ingreso al sistema y enviarla a un subdominio y si es posible ¿de que manera puedo realizar este evento?

Es decir si un usuario se logea en  <kbd>`dominio.com`</kbd> y da clic sobre un botón el cual lo redirige a <kbd>`sub.dominio.com`</kbd>

¿Cómo puedo hacer que la sesión se quede activa en `sub.dominio.com`?

Comment: cuando usas variable de `$_SESSION['ALGO']` quedan activas y si las necesitas en otro archivo solo necesitas habilitarla con `session_start()` de otro lado si quieres enviar variables normales lo puedes hacer atraves de un formulario o de una peticion

Comment: si, tenes que hacer un par de cambios en como se arma la sesión,  configurar el php.ini con session.cookie_domain = '.tudominio.com' o usar [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) antes del session_start

Answer (score 2):

En ambos scripts, prueba con :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.tudominio.com');
```

o editando el php.ini (los php.ini si son distintas instalaciones de php para cada subdominio)

```
session.cookie_domain = ".tudominio.com"
```

el  `.` adelante es importante para que tome los subdominios

Answer (score 0):

este ejemplo te puede ayudar

**midominio.com**
estas logueado en este dominio

```
$_SESSION['usuario']
```

**misubdominio.com**
tu session sigue activa  en este dominio

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    echo 'Usted no esta logueado';
    exit;
}else{
  echo 'Usted esta logueado';
}
```

Comment: cual es la funcion de ´session.cookie_domain´?

Comment: veo que tienes dudas muy basicas te recomiendo leer aserca de cookies y sessiones [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56157/uso-de-cookies-vs-session-en-php](aqui)

Comment: la pregunta va mas para subdominios, editando el php.ini se logra que los tome

Answer (score 0):

Podés guardar los datos en el dominio principal dentro de una cookie con setcookie() y utilizarlos en el subdominio para iniciar nuevamente la sesión con session_start().
Estos datos se guardan en las variables globales $_COOKIE y $_SESSION.

Documentación PHP:
http://php.net/manual/es/features.cookies.php

http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

Espero que sirva.
Saludos!