# ¿Cómo almacenar los datos de un formulario en una sesión?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema con el código que adjunto a continuación:

-En primer lugar, algo está fallando con el envío de las etiquetas "g_ciudad", "grabar" y "borrar"

-En segundo lugar, no sé cómo hacer que, si la sesión está ya establecida, aparezcan los valores seleccionados/introducidos de teléfono, cp y ciudad

Con el código pretendo hacer lo siguiente:

- Establecer un campo cp y uno telefono
- Establecer un desplegable de ciudades, además de un botón Grabar ciudad, que almacena la selección en una cookie
- Establecer dos botones: uno Guardar, que almacena los datos de cp y telefono en una sesión; y otro Borrar, que borra tanto los datos de
  cp y telefono en la sesión como la cookie con el dato de la ciudad
- Si no se ha establecido sesión, la página te dirige a otra llamada login.php
- Si la sesión ya está establecida, los valores introducidos/seleccionados deben aparecer por pantalla

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
<?php
// Iniciar sesion
session_start();

// Reseteo
$telefono = $cookie_ciudad = $ciudad = $cp = $error = $exito = '';

// Compruebas si existen por ejemplo sesion usuario
if ( isset($_SESSION['usuario']) ){
    // Formulario existe
    if (isset($_POST)){

        // Obtener datos
        
        if (isset($_POST['telefono']) && isset($_POST['cp']) && isset($_POST['ciudad'])){
            $_POST['telefono'] = $telefono;
            $_POST['cp'] = $cp;
            $_POST['ciudad'] = $ciudad; 
        }else{ 
            $telefono = '';
            $cp = '';
            $ciudad=''; 
        }

        // Guardar cuidad
        if(isset($_POST['g_ciudad'])) {
            // Caso que no existe
            if (empty($ciudad)){ 
                $error = 'Seleccione una ciudad';
            }else{
                // Crear cookie
                setcookie('cookie_ciudad', $ciudad, time()+3600);

                // Mensaje
                $exito = 'Cookie guardada';   
            }
        // Borrar sesion y cookie
        } elseif (isset($_POST['borrar'])) {
            // Eliminar sesion
            unset($_SESSION);
            session_destroy();

            // Destruir cookie.
            setcookie('cookie_ciudad', $ciudad, 1);

            // Mensaje
            $exito = 'Datos borrados';   

        // Guardar datos
        } elseif(isset($_POST['grabar'])) {
            // Datos no estan vacios
            if(!empty($telefono) && !empty($cp)){
                // Creas tus sesiones
                $_SESSION['telefono'] = $telefono;
                $_SESSION['cp'] = $cp; 
                $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] = $ciudad; 
                // Mensaje
                $exito = 'Sesión guardada';   
            // No existen datos       
            }else{
                $error = 'Introduzca un teléfono y un código postal';
            }    
        }
    }
// No existe session
}else{
    header('location: login.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(estilo.css);
    </style>
    <title>Sesión</title>
</head>

<body>

    <fieldset>
        <legend> </legend>

        <form action=' method='post'>
            <div>
                <label>Teléfono:</label>
                <input type='tel' name='telefono' value='<?php if (isset($_SESSION['telefono'])) echo $_SESSION['telefono'] ?>' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Código postal:</label>
                <input type='text' name='cp' value='<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cp'])) echo $_SESSION['cp'] ?>' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Ciudad:</label>
                <select name='ciudad' id='ciudad'>
                    <option value='huelva' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'huelva') echo 'selected'  ?>>Huelva</option>
                    <option value='sevilla' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'sevilla') echo 'selected'  ?>>Sevilla</option>
                    <option value='cordoba' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'cordoba') echo 'selected'  ?>>Córdoba</option>
                    <option value='cadiz' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'cadiz') echo 'selected'  ?>>Cádiz</option>
                    <option value='granada' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'granada') echo 'selected'  ?>>Granada</option>
                    <option value='malaga' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'malaga') echo 'selected'  ?>>Málaga</option>
                    <option value='jaen' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'jaen') echo 'selected'  ?>>Jaén</option>
                    <option value='almeria' <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cookie_ciudad']) && $_SESSION['cookie_ciudad'] == 'almeria') echo 'selected'  ?>>Almería</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='submit' value='Grabar ciudad' name='g_ciudad' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='submit' value='Grabar' name='grabar' />
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='Borrar' name='borrar' />

            <?php 
                if (isset($error)) echo $error;
                if (isset($exito)) echo $exito;
            ?>

        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. El fallo con el envío de las etiquetas "g_ciudad", "grabar" y "borrar" es porque estas intentando acceder a ellos sin que aún existe dichas claves:

   `if($_POST["g_ciudad"]){}` cambia lo por `if(isset($_POST["g_ciudad"])) {}`
2. En segundo lugar, no sé cómo hacer que, si la sesión está ya establecida, aparezcan los valores seleccionados/introducidos de teléfono, cp y ciudad

   Esto lo puedes hacer comprobando si existe la sesión o no:

   `<input type="tel" name="telefono" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['telefono'])) echo $_SESSION['telefono'] ?>" />`
3. Si no se ha establecido sesión, la página te dirige a otra llamada login.php, cogí sesión 'usuario', cambia lo por el tuyo:

   `if ( isset($_SESSION['usuario']) { // sesion existe } else { rediriges al login }`
4. Cambie tu action, ya que tu PHP está en la misma página que tu formulario según tu ejemplo:
   `<form action="" method="post">`

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
 <?php
// Iniciar sesion
session_start();

// Reseteo
$telefono = $cuidad = $cp = $error = $success = '';

// Compruebas si existen por ejemplo sesion usuario
if ( isset($_SESSION['usuario']) ) :
    // Formulario existe
    if (isset($_POST)) :

        // Obtener datos
        $telefono = $_POST["telefono"] ?? '';
        $cp = $_POST["cp"] ?? '';
        $ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"] ?? '';

        // Guardar cuidad
        if(isset($_POST["g_ciudad"])) {
            // Caso que no existe
            if (empty($ciudad)) : 
                $error = 'Selecciona una cuidad';
            else :
                // Crear cookie
                setcookie("cuidad", $ciudad, time()+3600);

                // Mensaje
                $success = 'Se guardo tu cookie';   
            endif;
        // Borrar sesion y cookie
        } elseif (isset($_POST['borrar'])) {
            // Eliminar sesion
            unset($_SESSION);
            session_destroy();

            // Destruir cookie.
            setcookie("cuidad", $ciudad, 1);

            // Mensaje
            $success = 'Se borraron los datos';   

        // Guardar datos
        } elseif(isset($_POST["grabar"])) {
            // Datos no estan vacios
            if(!empty($telefono) && !empty($cp)){
                // Creas tus sesiones
                $_SESSION["telefono"] = $telefono;
                $_SESSION["cp"] = $cp; 
                $_SESSION["cuidad"] = $ciudad; 
                // Mensaje
                $success = 'Se guardo la sesion';   
            // No existen datos       
            }else{
                $error = 'Selecciona un telefono y cp';
            }    
        }

    endif;
// No existe session
else:
    header('location: login.php');
endif;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(estilo.css);
    </style>
    <title>Sesión</title>
</head>

<body>

    <fieldset>
        <legend> </legend>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>Teléfono:</label>
                <input type="tel" name="telefono" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['telefono'])) echo $_SESSION['telefono'] ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Código postal:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cp" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cp'])) echo $_SESSION['cp'] ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Ciudad:</label>
                <select name="ciudad" id="ciudad">
                    <option value="huelva" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cuidad']) && $_SESSION['cuidad'] == 'huelva') echo 'selected'  ?>>Huelva</option>
                    <option value="sevilla" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cuidad']) && $_SESSION['cuidad'] == 'sevilla') echo 'selected'  ?>>Sevilla</option>
                    <option value="cordoba" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cuidad']) && $_SESSION['cuidad'] == 'cordoba') echo 'selected' //etc.. ?>>Córdoba</option>
                    <option value="cadiz">Cádiz</option>
                    <option value="granada">Granada</option>
                    <option value="malaga">Málaga</option>
                    <option value="jaen">Jaén</option>
                    <option value="almeria">Almería</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Grabar ciudad" name="g_ciudad" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Grabar" name="grabar" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Borrar" name="borrar" />

            <?php 
                if (isset($error)) echo $error;
                if (isset($success)) echo $success;
            ?>

        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Respecto al punto 4, el action si le pasas por ejemplo `action="sesion.php"` cuando das clic este te va a enviar a sesion.php y allí debería ir entonces el código PHP y no en la misma página, si es en la misma página la podrías incluso quitar. Resumiendo si pones un `action="cualquierpagina.php"` el codigo PHP de dicho formulario va alli.

Respecto al punto 3, si no se ha establecido sesión, la página te dirige a otra llamada login.php, me imagino que te refieres al usuario, ya que las sesiones que creas mediante el formulario en el ejemplo de arriba, no tendría sentido, ya que si no siempre te va a enviar al *login.php*, entonces con `if ( isset($_SESSION['usuario']) ) : {}` quiero decir, si la sesión del usuario existe, entonces se podra usar el formulario, en caso contrario te envía al login para que inicie sesión, ¿en tu login harás algo como `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $id_usuario;` si el login es válido me imagino? Entonces el formulario no se podra usar mientras el usuario no existe.

Quizás no te borra porque también cambie esta línea: `<input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="borrar" />` por `<input type="submit" value="Borrar" name="borrar" />`, fíjate que cambie el tipo **reset** por **submit**. A ver si es eso. A veces hay que limpiar también el cache del navegador para su efecto, en muchos funciona `ctrl + shift + r` para limpiarlo.

Comment: 1. Gracias. Tiene todo el sentido lo que propones

2. Igualmente aquí creo que vuelves a llevar razón

3. Aquí reconozco que no entiendo exactamente lo que me propones

4. ¿En qué cambia que elimine el contenido del action?

En cualquier caso, muchas gracias por la ayuda. No lo sé seguro, pero creo que todo funciona menos el guardar la cookie, que no sé por qué sigue sin guardarse y el borrar los datos de la sesión, que siguen manteniéndose

Comment: @dancareli te he dejado un apartado **Edit** en mi respuesta. Respecto a la **COOKIE** es raro, lo probe yo mismo en localhost y funciono todo: quizás te puede ayudar como usarlo esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56157/uso-de-cookies-vs-session-en-php/56166#56166, ¿has probado copiar mi código tal cual y probarlo aparte? recuerda que tiene que existir un usuario, si no esa parte la eliminas del código. Ya me comentas.

Comment: la verdad es que tu código funciona correctamente. No alcanzo a ver dónde está el problema, pero voy a ir analizando ambos códigos para ver dónde puede estar. Si encuentro alguna cosa lo comento por aquí, pero muchas gracias por todo

Comment: @dancareli a veces pasan cosas raras por pequeños fallos. Si quieres edita tu pregunta, y pon el nuevo ejemplo con las modificaciones que has hecho con respecto a mi ejemplo, a ver si veo algún error. Para verificar la COOKIE puedes hacer ```$_COOKIE["cuidad"]```. Lo único fíjate que yo puse **cuidad** y tus pones **ciudad**, no sé si es eso, pero revisa a ver si es por poner mal el nombre. Al menos has visto que funciona mi ejemplo :)

Comment: he editado la pregunta para poner el código que tengo actualmente. He modificado los if-else para indicarlos todos con llaves. Además, he cambiado "cuidad" por "cookie_ciudad" que creo que es más intuitivo. Y por último, como no entiendo la sintaxis $telefono = $_POST["telefono"] ?? ''; porque no sé qué significan los **?? ''** y para que no me saltara el error de variable indefinida, los he puesto como $_POST["telefono"] = $telefono;  El problema es que la variable "ciudad" sigue dándome el error de variable indefinida en las líneas 16 y 37 y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Además, ahora los botones no funcionan

Comment: Lo acabo de cargar en localhost y veo el fallo: ```Warning: Undefined variable $ciudad``` ahora reviso el código y lo adapto. Respecto a ```$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"] ?? '';``` con esto **?? ''** estamos obteniendo el valor de $_POST si existe y si no existe va ser una cadena vacía, por eso ponemos **''**

Comment: Entonces eso último que comentas es equivalente a:

if (isset($_POST["ciudad])){
$_POST["ciudad"]=$ciudad;
}else{
$ciudad='';
}

Comment: Fíjate que no reseteaste **$ciudad** aquí: ```$telefono = $cookie_ciudad = $cp = $ciudad = $error = $success = '';``` cámbialo así: ```$telefono = $cookie_ciudad = $cp = $ciudad = $error = $success = '';```, es importante resetear variables que vamos usar. Dame un poco de tiempo, que voy a comer y reviso el código. Luego esto debes dejarlo así: ```$telefono = $_POST["telefono"] ?? '';``` y no ```$_POST["telefono"] = $telefono;```

Comment: Si seria lo mismo, pero abreviado a partir de PHP 8, si pones por ejemplo: ```$cuidad = (isset($_POST["ciudad"])) ? $_POST["ciudad"] : '';``` logras lo mismo.

Comment: Pues voy a usarlo con el if, ya que ahora mismo, que estoy empezando, me parece más intuitivo a la hora de leer lo que está pasando. He vuelto a modificar el código de la pregunta para añadir esta última modificación

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135065/discussion-between-dbe-and-dancareli).