# ¿Cómo guardar una variable php en cookies?

Tags: variables, php8, setcookie

En una página registro.php tengo un script php que valida un formulario, de no cumplirse redirecciona a la página del formulario, en la misma quiero que aparezca el siguiente mensaje cuando sea redireccionada:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">
    alert("Anda a hackearle el **** a tu abuela");
</script>';
```

El detalle es que no encuentro la manera de hacerlo. Intenté con guardarlo en una cookie pero no hace nada. En la linea 41 hago un var_dump para comprovar y me da "NULL", y no entiendo por qué no guarda la variable, si lo hice igual al ejemplo en el sitio de PHP.

Este es el código para guardar la variable:

```
//Esta es la validación del lado backend contra malintencionados :p
if(!preg_match('/^J\d*-\d*$/', $rif))
  {
  //Declarar variable del mensaje Ofensivo :D
  $mensajeOfensivo = 'Anda a hackearle el **** a tu abuela';
  //Guardamos la variable en el almacen Cache por 30 segundos
  setcookie("mensajeOfensivo", $mensajeOfensivo, time()+30);
  //page3.php
  header("Location: http://localhost/Benfran21Store/page3.php", TRUE, 301);
  exit();
  }
```

Este es el código para extraer el cookie (el cual si funciona y me dice que no existe):

```
echo $_COOKIE["mensajeOfensivo"];
```

El notice que dice que no existe:

```
Notice: Undefined index: mensajeOfensivo in C:\...\page3.php on line 41
```

Comment: En la pregunta deberias incluir la línea 41 del archivo registro.php y su contexto (es decir, cómo recuperas esa variable antes de usarla en esa línea), pues es allí donde se produce el problema. O bien asegurarte que el setcookie funciona encerrandolo en un condicional tipo:  `if (!setcookie("mensajeOfensivo", $mensajeOfensivo, time()+30);) { echo "Error!! No he podido establecer la cookie! Revisar si hay algo antes en la salida!!"; die();}`

Comment: Como te ha dicho materguru, comprueba que la COOKIE se está creando, ya que el mensaje **Undefined index: mensajeOfensivo** es porque la clave no existe en tu ```echo $_COOKIE["mensajeOfensivo"];```, con lo cual no te está creando la COOKIE, para evitar el error has: ```if (isset($_COOKIE["mensajeOfensivo"])) echo $_COOKIE["mensajeOfensivo"];```, luego comprueba porque no te está creando la COOKIE, mira si tu condicional funciona ```if(!preg_match('/^J\d*-\d*$/', $rif)) { echo 'entro en la condicional'; }```

Comment: Gracias masterguru, ya edite la pregunta que si me explique mal. Tu if funciona, y sigue dando el mismo error.

Gracias DBE, tu if funciona y sigue dando el mismo error. Ahora me pregunto si estará bien escrito $_COOKIE["mensajeOfensivo"];

Por comodidad subí el archivo aquí: https://mega.nz/file/uQBWkJYI#SiRl1vka_2K6Op3YfV-k0Vpq3yTNNjYY_oDW0YVza14

Comment: Estas accediendo correctamente a la COOKIE con ```$_COOKIE["mensajeOfensivo"]; ```, fíjate en esta respuesta de crear una COOKIE quizás te ayuda y nos comentas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56157/uso-de-cookies-vs-session-en-php/56166#56166